# Serve web pages from directory other than /var/www

Tags: apache, ubuntu-12.04, sage, document-root

I want my web pages to be served from my server's root directory (/root/.sage) instead of /var/www .
I am using `Apache Tomcat` as server on `Ubuntu`.
Could anyone please let me know all the steps involved.

Comment: Use DocumentRoot in a VirtualHost block to point at the directory you need to use.  You'll probably also need to make sure Apache can read and write some files.

Comment: Have a look on [Apache Tomcat Configuration Reference](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know many details about this, but you may find https://github.com/sagemath/sagenb/pull/328 to be useful.